# GCC bug? long long divided by unsigned long

Tags: 64-bit, division

What should the output of this program be?  Ubuntu C++ (4.8.4) gives 1954495122 which doesn't look like the right answer.  The bits are all wrong for it to be a signed/unsigned thing.

The interesting thing is if I change 'n' from an unsigned long to an unsigned int, I get the correct answer: -17753859.

Mingw and Visual Studio both give the same 'correct' answer.

It's hard to find out what the standard says about this particular operation but even if it were 'implementation defined' I would assume that the answer would make some sort of sense.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long long s = -88769298432;
    unsigned long n = 5000;
    int x = (int)(s / n);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I should note that I've tried some other values and they seem to work so it isn't completely obvious why those values work.

And, I came up with these because I was trying to track down a portability bug between Windows and Linux.  The problem was that I was trying to find the average of a vector.  The 's' above was the sum.  The 'n' was the number of elements in the vector (v.size() which is defined as an unsigned long in gcc).  The errant answer was the Linux answer.  Casting the 'n' in the denominator to (int) fixed it.

weird.

thanks,
marco

Comment: My guess is that you are using a 64 bit compiler on Ubuntu. I bet if you compile for 32bit it would work. Your problem is on the line `unsigned long n = 5000;` . To give you a hint of why this is happening, compile your source code with `-Wsign-conversion` g++ compiler flag  . It should generate a warning. On systems where g++ is used and sizeof(s) and sizeof(n) are the same you will likely have issues.

Comment: I didn't realize that sizeof(long) was 8 on that compiler and should have checked.